# Misbehaving Get-ChildItem Operation in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

There is a back-end SQL DB contains "managed folders" in the form of UNC paths. Using SQL queries in PowerShell I have a loop that will work it's way through these folders and run a GCI operation against them to work out how much disk space they are using.

```
$managedFolder = "\\server\share\folder\subfolder"
```

For the sake of the question, `$managedFolder` is declared as above. The failing command below:

```
$diskTrendsInitialUsage = "{0:N2}" -f ((Get-ChildItem $managedFolder -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1GB)
```

Now if I were to run this command manually in PS console it's fine, it pulls back data. But as soon as it's packaged in a script, it fails with the below error. The folder is accessible from the server, as it works fine from a local PS console session.

```
ERROR: Get-ChildItem : Invalid Path: '\\server\share\folder\subfolder'.
AddManagedFolder.psf (17): ERROR: At Line: 17 char: 42
ERROR: +         $diskTrendsInitialUsage = "{0:N2}" -f ((Get-ChildItem $managedFolder -Recurse  ...
ERROR: +                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
ERROR:
```

I'm stumped.

Comment: Do you have some special characters in the Path string? brackets, etc.

Comment: Nope, it's just a plain UNC path.

Comment: It could be however that some subfolders have parenthesis or other brackets? Try using -LiteralPath

Comment: But it works fine via a standard PS console, just not when executed via .ps1 scripts.

Comment: Same behavior with literalPath either way.

Comment: I just realized you are using a PSF file. Is that Posh Sec Framework? Maybe try a classic Powershell PS1 script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67998/discussion-between-pnp-and-micky-balladelli).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with your path is that it does not have any indication about which provider to use, so PowerShell just use current one. And if current provider is not a file system provider, then it will fail. So you need to specify provider in path, to allow PowerShell to choose right one regardless of current provider:

```powershell
$managedFolder = "filesystem::\\server\share\folder\subfolder"
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is your are using the SQL PS cmdlets prior to running GCI, this is changing your provider path to SQL: which is what is causing GCI to be unhappy.

Prior to running GCI do `cd c:\` to change the path back to the file system and GCI will work.

Comment: Thanks Noah, I decided to with the above option as thats keeps the code cleaner, but many thanks for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. He used my information to post his answer, but specifying it that way is definitely cleaner.